uxcam isn't tagging screen name in my flutter app
I was integrating Uxcam with my flutter app and i was trying to set screen tagging. As i'm using GoRouter I followed the GoRouter part in their official documentation : UXcam Flutter tagging approach
but unfortunately it still returns undefined screen name in my dashboard
first a set enableAutomaticScreenNameTagging to false in Uxcam config
then as the documentation mentioned i added the observer for Uxcam in Gorouter
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    ...
 observers: [
    FlutterUxcamNavigatorObserver(),
 ],
    ...
)

but screens don't get tagged
